# ASP.NET Core exception "View was not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I created a solution with multiple applications and I configure routes like this :

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ControlPanel",
                template: "ControlPanel/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

I can navigate to ControlPanel project and it goes into ihome controller in but i shows this error :
[image]

I find out that it sets base directory in my program.cs when project runs first time and it is my main webapplication assembly name (CustomerProject) :

[image]

so now how can I change ContentDirectory and wwwroot directory to new assembly name?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you went to URL has controller name without specifying action method or it was smth like this `yourhost/iHome/Index`, so as for result you have executed `Index` action of `iHome` controller and there is no `Index.cshtml` in your solution. View engine can't find a specific page for your request, so try to add `Index.cshtml` into `/Views/iHome/` or into `/Views/Shared/` folders. 
Also, I can suggest reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) for common understanding how views discovery works.

Comment: You dont understand my question and i dont know why you edit my question. in my case it cannot find bcuz project and assembly name changes and content root still is last name, and it search in last project views folder. now do you understand my problem?

Comment: @HatefGnani, could you attach a screenshot with folder structure of your solution?